# Getting Progress Webspeed working on IIS8.5

Tags: iis, openedge, webspeed

I am migrating several websites from a windows server 2003 box to windows server 2012. 2 of them connect to a Progress back-end via "Webspeed Messenger"

I have followed everything I can find regarding this but I am getting nowhere.

When I try to run these sites all I get is this intriguing error:

[image]

Intriguing because "Webspeed" is mis-spelled "We**d**speed"

Any help would be much appreciated! I get the feeling this is extremely old technology here trying to run on a current server platform...

Answer (score 1):

10.2B is indeed old technology. Released in 2009 it's no longer considered the pinnacle of invention. Current version is 11.5, with 11.6 just around the corner.

However getting 10.2B to work in current versions of IIS should be not great problem.

**There are a couple of knowledge base entries regarding this error:**

[WebSpeed error in the browser: Failed to load WSMSGP.DLL or WSUTIL.DLL.WSISA.ERR](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P7502)

[Webspeed CGIIP Messenger Error loading wsmsgp.dll](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P190921)

[Getting error regarding loading wsmsgp.dll when using the WebSpeed Messenger cgiip.exe](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000046474)

The last one suggests that this has to do with file permissions. The two first one discusses corrupt files.

**General troubleshooting**

Whenever you encounter problems with WebSpeed or the Appserver (WebSpeed is actually part of the AppServer technology) you should look into the various log files available. The two most interesting ones are by default named:

- wsbroker1.server.log
- wsbroker1.broker.log

and are placed in the working directory. Typically c:\openedge\wrk or something similar. This can however depend on your setup.

You should also look in access logs and error logs for IIS. They might reveal more information!

When you have gathered more information you can search the knowledgebase:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/

as well as look in the official forums:

https://community.progress.com/

(Reading wont require you to log in)

There you can also find the complete product documentation (even for your old version):

[10.2B Product Documentation](https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1164.openedge-10-2b-product-documentation.aspx)

Comment: Well.. I'm getting somewhere at least, I have completely scrubbed and reinstalled the messenger package (there were fragmented bits everywhere) and now I get a message saying "Unable to find web object file 'foo.r'"

I have done a direct copy of the ubroker.properties file from the 2003 server, so in theory it should connect to the same server. 

hmm...

Comment: You need to inspect your log files. That error is atleast an error from Progress. Are the file layouts and Progress setup the same?